# Замена элементов в списке

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть слово , нужно его разбить по буквам и каждой букве присвоить порядковый номер в порядке расположения этой буквы в алфавите. Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал класс с двумя полями типа `char` и `int`. Дошёл до того как получил порядковый номер в алфавите, а как заменить номера из алфавита порядковым номером именно в слове не могу придумать.
Получается вот такой список:

```
Р   А   Д   О   С   Т   Ь   
17  1   5   15  18  19  29
```

Comment: Приведите листинг своего кода, чтобы помогли Вам его доделать.

Comment: Кода нет никакого, мозг не может сообразить как сделать это без сортировки(, которая мне не нужна

Comment: А если в слове несколько одинаковых букв?

Comment: @Qwertiy при работе такого не будет, это не нужно учитывать

Comment: Вы пошто букву "ё" обидели? Она тоже занимает позицию в алфавите. Сейчас у вас 32 буквы получается.

Comment: @TagirValeev я согласен с it-алфавитом, и считаю что ё не нужна)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java-8. Сперва отсортируем индексы позиций в слове по возрастанию (сравниваем символы просто по номеру; если сильно надо, можно `Collator` прикрутить):

```
String word = "РАДОСТЬ";
int[] revRanks = IntStream.range(0, word.length()).boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(word::charAt)).mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
```

Затем обратим перестановку (тупо сортировкой, но работает) и добавим единичку:

```
int[] ranks = IntStream.range(0, revRanks.length).boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(idx -> revRanks[idx])).mapToInt(i -> i+1)
        .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ranks));
```

Результат:

```
[4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/RL2794)

Comment: Результат не тот что нужен, нужен не номер в алфавите, это сделать легко , а так как на картинке в начале поста)

Comment: @МихаилКетов, виноват, неправильно понял задачу. Исправил решение. Это тоже сделать легко. Вы лучше картинки не вставляйте, а так пишите.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю на сколько это хорошо и быстро работает, но хоть как.

```
result.addAll(keyList);

//      Сортировка по символам
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.size() - i - 1; j++) {
            if (result.get(j).getSymbol() > result.get(j + 1).getSymbol()) {
                Key t = result.get(j);
                result.set(j, result.get(j + 1));
                result.set(j + 1, t);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
        result.get(i).setNumber(numInKey++);
    }
    //Возвращение обратно
    for(int i = 0; i < keyList.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < result.size(); j++){
            if(keyList.get(i).getSymbol() == result.get(j).getSymbol()){
                keyList.get(i).setNumber(result.get(j).getNumber());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

- Заполняем HashMap (учитывая уникальность букв по заданию) буквами, значения - нулевые.
- Циклом по алфавиту заполняем в HashMap'е значения счетчиком существующих букв.
- По букве в слове можем получить порядковый номер в алфавитном порядке.
- Профит.

На скорую руку и без алфавита (для самостоятельного решения):

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> letters = new HashMap();
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
    letters.put(input.charAt(i), 0);
}
int k=0;
for(int j=0;j<'z'-'a';j++){
    Character c = Character.toChars('a'+j)[0];
    if(letters.containsKey(c)){
        letters.put(c,k);
        k++;
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
    Character c = input.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(c+" "+letters.get(c));
}
```

https://ideone.com/vPuYfM

Comment: от моего варианта мало чем отличается), я просто думал что эту задачу можно решить без таких созданий/копирований листов

Comment: @МихаилКетов Как минимум у вас будет O(n^2), у меня O(n) - алгоритмы разные, почему они "мало чем отличаются", не знаю.